# QtLocation crash on close under Windows, no crash under Android

Tags: android, windows, qt, qtlocation

I am developing an Android application which uses the QtLocation module. The problem is, after closing the map window / or closing the application under Windows the application crashes. If I start the exact same application under Android there is no crash.
The same is happening when I use the "minimal_map" example, available in the QtCreator: The error message is APPCRASH in Qt5Locationd.dll.

The crash only happens when closing the window, until then, everything seems fine.

Do you have an idea why this is happening? 

The map code looks like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtLocation 5.6
import QtPositioning 5.6

Window {
    width: 512
    height: 512
    visible: true

    Plugin {
        id: osmPlugin
        name: "osm"
    }

    Map {
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: osmPlugin
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(59.91, 10.75) // Oslo
        zoomLevel: 10
    }
}
```

I use MSVC2015 as the build environment, to build for Windows.

Comment: Is qt 5.6 that you are using? As this was a bug recently solved in 5.8 which didn't seem to exist in 5.6

Comment: I installed the development environment onto a different pc and there it works. Also the bug was only happening when building "Debug" instead of "Release".